# Swift UI + iOS 14.5 + Kingfisher + NavigationLink View

Tags: swiftui, kingfisher

Since the upgrade of iOS to 14.5, my child view from a NavigationLink doesn't show the images from Kingfisher/Firebase.  Just a blank image, but constraints are still in affect, the space of the blank image.  If I change it to a sheet which I don't want to do, the image appears. Any suggestions?

```
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: CommentView(postVM: postVM),
                    label: {
                        Text("Comments")
                    })
                
//                Button(action: {
//                    activeSheet = .viewComments
//                }, label: {
//                    Text("Comments")
//                })
            } // END:HSTACK
```

Here is the child view or view which NavigationLink takes you too.  If I use non Kingfisher image it displays like it should.  Also if I use a .sheet to display the view the Kingfisher image is loaded properly. Also, if I don't use any modifies, like .resizable(), .scaledToFit/Fill() the image displays. This all worked until update.

```
            // MARK: - POST IMAGE
            if postVM.post.postImgUrl.isEmpty {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 5)
            } else {
                KFImage(URL(string: postVM.post.postImgUrl))
                //Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(maxHeight: 440)
            }
```

[image]

[image]